# Probability - Consecutive, intermittent, and halved?

Tags: probability

so this is going to be a four-part question. The beginning information is: Studies of weather show that, historically, Naples, Florida is hit by a hurricane every 12 years. Calculate the following probabilities based on the historical record.

The first problem asks for the probability of Naples getting hit by a hurricane in any given year, and asks to express it as proportion with four decimal places and a fraction. I believe I did this right by doing answering: 1/12 or 0.0833. Now, the second problem is where I begin to get confused.

It asks for the probability of Naples being hit in each of the three consecutive years. I tried to answer this by doing: (1/12)*(1/12)*(1/12). That gives me 1/1728. I feel however this is incorrect. And since I set this question up this way I have no idea how to set the other two up.

The third question asks for the probability of Naples being hit by a hurricane in either the next year or the next two years after. I didn't do any work, but logically I came up with 3/12 or 1/4 chance of this happening. Did I do that correctly?

Finally, the last question asks for the probability of Naples being hit by at least one hurricane in the next six years. How would I even start to go about this? Would it be 6/12? That's what I came up with, though I know it can't be correct since I have to answer the question as a percentage with 3 decimal places. I feel like it has to be an uglier number, but I don't know how else to set it up. The only other idea I had was a 1/24 chance since its twice as unlikely to happen in 6 years compared to 12 years. But beyond that I'm lost. Can anyone advise? I really need the help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should review the exponential distribution. Your parameter lambda is 1/12 here.

Comment: Are you familiar with exponential distribution?